# bash script to automatize python script problem

Tags: python, bash

i have an issue with a bash script, it runs a python script over all the csv files that i have inside in a directory, but i have notice the resultant files are incomplete, any file contains more than 100 rows,and curiously it left to write in the row number 100
i include my bash code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find ./nodos_aleatorios100 -type f -name '*.csv' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
        nname=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/ecn/encn/") 
        python algoritmo_aleatorio.py $line $nname
    done
```

and the question is how can solve this problem?
thanks in advance to everyone could help me,

Comment: This seems like it must be a problem with the python script, not the bash script. I'd recommend double-quoting the filenames (i.e. `python algoritmo_aleatorio.py "$line" "$nname"`), but I don't see how that could have anything to do with the 100-row problem.

Comment: thanks mate, i'm going to check my python code,

Comment: @EdwinReyes : Instead of fiddling around with `-print0` and `IFS`, why don't you simply do the whole thing in Python? You don't use any bash feature which couldn't easily be done in Python.  BTW, your assignment to `nname` could more concisely be written as `nname=$(sed s/ecn/encn/ <<<"$line")`

Comment: Actually, you can do that substitution as part of the bash variable expansion, without even using `sed`: nname=${line/ecn/encn}`